# Running a Vonage router behind a Linksys Firewall

Tags: voip

I have a Vonage router used for outgoing VOIP calls.  It gets a LAN ip by connecting to a Linksys WRT54g via DHCP.  From there, it cannot actually get a WAN ip or connect out.

What do I need to port forward?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have to port forward anything, it actually calls home to the Vonage mothership, but I wasn't receiving "dial tone" until I called them and had it activated.

If you have a Vonage Motorola vt2142, you can browse to it's IP address. Default login is router/router. The provisioning status should give you a little clue as to whats going on.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by several things.  This issue is discussed in quite a bit of detail over on the Vonage forums here:

http://www.vonage-forum.com/ftopic9056.html

There are 3 pages to that particular thread so be sure to read through it all as there are several different problems and solutions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to assign the Vonage unit a static IP address in your DHCP server.  Then configure that IP as the DMZ port in your firewall.  This will forward anything not already forwarded to the unit.  This gives your Vonage unit access to all the ports it needs.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that UDP Ports 62265,10000-20000 are used with the new Vonage routers.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to bypass the vonage and this will avoid you port forward from it.

usually your internet with a vonage service is connected like this:
Internet modem => Vonage VoIP router => wireless router
instead do this:
Internet modem => wireless router => Vonage VoIP router to one of the ports.

This works wonders for me and only have to do port forwarding on my linksys (192.168.1.1) and leave Vonage (192.168.15.1) alone.
Also my phone works perfectly with no further port changes on my router.